# Assigning the Policy Set(Azure Initiative) using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

I am able to assign an Azure policy using the command `New-AzPolicyAssignment`. Below is the document which has information about this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azpolicysetdefinition?view=azps-2.1.0

**But I want to assign a policy set, how can I assign a policy set using Powershell?**

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "subscriptionidhere"
$PolicySet = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition -Name "plociysetguidhere"
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'Name here' -PolicySetDefinition $PolicySet -Scope "/subscriptions/subscriptionidhere"
```

You can find the Policy set GUID by just running the `Get-AzPolicySetDefinition`, this will pull all the policy sets for your subscription

Comment: Small correction. `Get-AzPolicySetDefinition` expects string as a name param, not GUID. So it should be `-Name "PolicySetDefinitionID"` instead

Comment: @avinash, just mark your answer as answered.

Comment: In my case the policies were part ARM template. So I used `New-AzDeployment -Name "XYZ"  -TemplateFile "arm.json"`

Answer (score 1):

To complete your answer, this is an example of how you assign an initiative with `New-AzPolicyAssignment`:

```
$ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name 'ResourceGroup11'
$intiative = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Properties.DisplayName -eq 'denyPolicies' }
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name 'denyPolicies' -PolicySetDefinition $intiative -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
```